# vba programming code to click on Span in a webpage

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer

HTML:

```
<tr id="m48482eee_tbod_tdrow-tr[R:16]"     class="tablerow   trodd" style="display:;" >
<td role="presentation" headers='m48482eeeerrtitle[R:-1]' aria-labelledby='m48482eeeerrtitle[R:-1]' class='tc' style='border-right:0px; width: 1px;'><img id='m48482eee_tbod_tdrow-tr[R:16]_er_img' src='blank.gif' style='display:none' class='tablerow_blank_icon' title="" alt=""/></td> <td id="m48482eee_tdrow_[C:0]-c[R:16]" tablecell="1"     class="tc cd" headers="m48482eee_ttrow_[C:0]-c"  >
<span id="m48482eee_tdrow_[C:0]_ttxt-lb[R:16]" align='left' ctype="label"    tabindex="0"      targetid="m48482eee_tdrow_[C:0]_ttxt-lb[R:16]"  mxevent="click"  class="text label   anchor" style="padding:0px;padding-left:1px;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;cursor:pointer;">INVTROPPR - Transfer Opportunities for Items Under Max</span>

    </td>
```

This is my code

```
For Each obj In ie.Document.forms(0).getElementsByTagName("span")
    If obj.innerText = "INVTROPPR - Transfer Opportunities for Items Under 
    Max" Then
       obj.parentElement.Click
       Exit For
    End If
Next
```

I want to click on a Span in a the HTML above. I tried to run the above code, but this is not working, where is the problem?

Comment: No question and no code!

Comment: Please include your vba code and why the javascript tag? I can see HTML. Also, format your html properly. I have simply edited so it will display.

Comment: what does doesn't work mean?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
ie.document.querySelector("[tabindex='0']").click
```

Or

```
ie.document.querySelector("[tabindex='0']").FireEvent "onclick"
```

These target the element by its attribute `tabindex` and its value.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I am still not able click the span

Comment: I am not getting any error message but the above code gets executed and the span is not clicked

Comment: is using selenium basic an option?

Comment: @shikhar, can you please inform us what happen if you manually click on that span tag? further, try to debug your VBA code and check that it is finding the correct span and clicking on it or not. you can try to inform us your testing results. We will try to provide further suggestions, If needed.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT When I manually click on that particular span tag, it opens a new form...

Comment: other work around can be to add a link inside the span in HTML. So when you click using the code, that link will take you to the new form.

Comment: Perhaps there is a js event that needs triggering.